# Error decoding mixed encoding JSON string

Tags: python, json, unicode, decode, arabic

I have trouble parsing a `dict` with a `list` that contains both `ascii` and `unicode`. This is my pretty string:

```
pretty_string = """{
    "list": [
        "this_keyword_in_ascii",
        u"\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0633\u062f",                  # unicoded arabic
        u"\u0633\u0648\u0631\u064a\u0627",
        u"\u0627\u0644\u0625\u0631\u0647\u0627\u0628"
    ]
}
"""
```

I get the following error when decoding with `dict = cjson.decode(pretty_string)`: `DecodeError('cannot parse JSON description')`.

I've tried `pretty_string.decode('unicode_escape')` to no avail.  Please help!

Comment: Is this downvoted because it's a stupid question?

Comment: do You really  want to decode python dict? (or encode)

Comment: OK, now I realise that it's a string, but it has _absolutely nothing_ to do with JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do **not** have a JSON string. You have a Python literal. Use the [`ast.literal_eval()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead:

```
>>> literal_eval('''\
... {
...     "list": [
...         "this_keyword_in_ascii",
...         u"\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0633\u062f",                  # unicoded arabic
...         u"\u0633\u0648\u0631\u064a\u0627",
...         u"\u0627\u0644\u0625\u0631\u0647\u0627\u0628"
...     ]
... }
... ''')
{'list': ['this_keyword_in_ascii', u'\u0627\u0644\u0623\u0633\u062f', u'\u0633\u0648\u0631\u064a\u0627', u'\u0627\u0644\u0625\u0631\u0647\u0627\u0628']}
```

JSON strings never start with `u""`, that is a Python notation. Nor does JSON mix byte values and unicode values, JSON strings are always Unicode.

You may want to look into what produces this structure; perhaps the produces of this string should be using `json.dumps()` instead of `print`, `str()` or `repr()`.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to decode as JSON a string containing a *Python dictionary*. You should either use `decode` with JSON, or `encode` with your Python dict.